# IE toolbar respond when page has downloaded

Tags: windows, internet-explorer

How to make a IE toolbar respond to everytime a page is completed downloaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sink [DWebBrowserEvents2::DocumentComplete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768283(VS.85).aspx).